# How a pass a dynamic string to $regex in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I have two collections 1 is campaigns and other is orders. I have to filter orders for each campaign. So what I am doing is that I'm fetching all the campaigns and after that I'm looking up for the orders that matches some specific criteria.

```
[
 { 
   $match: { type: 'FOLLOWUP' } 
 },
 {
   $lookup: {
     from: 'orders',
     as: 'orders',
     pipeline: [
       {
          $match: {
             'title': { $regex: '$keyword', $options: 'i' },
          }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

In above example every campaign contains a `keyword` field of type `string`. So I have to filter all the orders for every campaign that contains the `keyword` in their `title` and each campaign have a different keyword. How can I pass a dynamic reference to $regex, if I'm using a hard coded string it's working fine but for passing reference ('$keyword') it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) aggregation expression operator,

- `let` to pass `keyword` from campaigns collection to lookup
- `$regexMatch` aggregation expression operator to pass input as `title` and regex as `keyword` reference from `let` using `$$` sign

```
[
  { $match: { type: "FOLLOWUP" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      as: "orders",
      let: { keyword: "$keyword" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$title",
                regex: "$$keyword",
                options: "i"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cTB_mSeOeLw)